# Cantor-Lebesgue construction: Construct a function $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$ that is non-decreasing $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$ and $F'(x)=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

Construct a function $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$ that is non-decreasing $F(0)=0$, $F(1)=1$ and $F'(x)=0$ a.e. with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

I am stuck on it. Can anyone give a good example?

Updated:

(1) Here is my construction: Based on Cantor Lebesgue construction, first take $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$. Then take $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x$ on $[0,\frac{1}{3}]$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ on $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]$, and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}(x-\frac{2}{3})$ on $[\frac{2}{3},1]$. Then repeat this process for $n$ times, always leaving the middle piece constant.

Is this available?

(2) I have a new question arisen from Cantor Lebesgue construction: Suppose I take an element $x\in[0,1]$, and use binary expansion as $x=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_j}{2^j}$, where $a_j=0,1$. Define the map $T(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_j}{3^j}$ where $b_j=0$ if $a_j=0$ and $b_j=2$ if $a_j=1$.

Claim: If $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure then $\mu T^{-1}$ will provide an counterexample.

I do not understand this claim. And what is the relation to the Lebesgue-Cantor construction I provided?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: Take $f(x)=0$ whenever $0\le x\le 1/2,$ and $f(x)=1$ for $1/2<x\le 1.$

Comment: Hi, can anyone check my construction and help me answer my second question?

Comment: @Allowander ... OP forgot to say "continuous", making the question much easier.